# How does sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/AAA/!d;' works to print paragraph

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Can anyone please explain how does the below sed command works to print a paragraph?

Command:

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/AAA/!d;' file
```

If possible can anyone explain by breaking this command into pieces so that i can full understand how to modify the command as per different condition.

Comment: Read [_mikeserv_'s answer there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136252/22142).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/AAA/!d;' file
```

prints paragraphs that contain the string `AAA`.

This invokes `sed` with the following `sed` script:

```
/./{
    H
    $!d
}
x
/AAA/!d
```

Annotated version:

```
/./{        # When hitting a line that contains at least one character...
    H;      # Append the line to the "hold space".
    $!d;    # If it's not the last line, delete it.
}
x;          # Swap the hold space and the pattern space.
/AAA/!d;    # Delete the pattern space if it does not contain the string "AAA"
            # (implicit print)
```

So, in short, it collects line after line in the "hold space" (a general purpose buffer in `sed`), and when it finds an empty line (the `/./` pattern does not match), it determines if the stored collection of lines contain the string `AAA` and prints it if it does.

This is also described in an answer here: [GREP / SED or AWK: Print entire paragraph in a file on pattern match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136218/grep-sed-or-awk-print-entire-paragraph-in-a-file-on-pattern-match)

Given the file

```
this is
a paragraph

this is
another one

this paragraph
contains the string
AAA
```

It would output the last paragraph (with a leading empty line).

To get rid of the empty line that will be preceding each outputted paragraph (if this is what you want), use

```
/./{
    H
    $!d
}
x
/AAA/!d
s/\n//
```

Or, on the command line

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/AAA/!d;s/\n//'
```

Comment: does this mean that it will not print anything after string **AAA**, within the same paragraph???

Comment: @UtkarshMishra It will always print the full paragraph regardless of where `AAA` occurs.