# AWK don't match line feed \n on gsub

Tags: awk

AWK don't match line feed `\n` on *gsub()*.
Want change only the 'strawberry' fruit entry below.
Would be great with sed too.

It ignores `\n` as you can see on this script:

```
cat << 'EOF' > ~/src
apple
fruit
strawberry
fruit
orange
fruit
blackberry
EOF
cat << 'EOF' > ~/scp.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat ~/src | awk '{ gsub("strawberry\nfruit", "strawberry\nfruitIsRed"); print }' > ~/trg
EOF
sh ~/scp.sh
diff ~/src ~/trg
# files are equals
```

Comment: cat ~/src | awk -v RS= '{ gsub("strawberry\nfruit", "strawberry\nfruitIsRed"); print }' > ~/trg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because awk's default RS (Record Separator) is a `\n`ewline, so awk never sees `\n`ewline anywhere to replace it and for that you need set RS to something else in order to recognize newline character, one way is setting RS to Null string (means records are separated with empty lines instead of newline):

```
awk -v RS= '{ "do stuffs" }'
```

and so it's not specific for *gsub()* only but RS dependent.

Comment: what 'RS dependent' mean, related with sed too ?

Comment: means whatever RS value takes, you cannot match that character (or regex) in your awk code, but with RT you can access its value. some `sed` implementation doesn't see it  in LHS (matching side), but some does, some you can enter actual newline too. for more about newline in sed, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114943/72456

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `RS=` has side effects - I'd point to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136305/315749) for an example/brief explanation. Here, it is relevant to note that `printf '%s\n%s\n' a b | awk -v RS= '/a\nb/'` is fine while `printf '%s\n\n%s\n' a b | awk -v RS= '/a\n\nb/'` won't give the likely expected result.

Comment: @fra-san that's what I mentioned here in advance https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/639770/awk-dont-match-line-feed-n-on-gsub/639771#comment1199127_639771, `RS=`==`RS='\n\n'`

Comment: @αғsнιη Oh, sorry, I didn't read carefully enough. But I also wanted to underline that `RS=` is "special" in that it separates records on sequences of 2 _or more_ newlines (and also removes empty lines from the output), which may be surprising to the reader. Not really a relevant point, though. Never mind.

Comment: `RS=` isn't quite == `RS='\n\n'`. It's close to `RS='\n\n+'` but not equivalent to that either (try `printf '\nfoo\n\nbar\n' | awk -v RS= '{print NR, "<" $0 ">"}'` vs `printf '\nfoo\n\nbar\n' | awk -v RS='\n\n+' '{print NR, "<" $0 ">"}'`) as `RS=''` has rules about ignoring leading/trailing newlines, just like the default FS ignores leading/trailing blanks. Also `RS=""` will work in all awks while `RS='\n\n+'` will only work in an awk that accepts a multi-char regexp as the RS (e.g. gawk). If you're using gawk, you can alternatively consider using `RS='^$'` to read the whole input at once.